# How to use graphics module and Tkinter module at the same time?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("hello world")
root.geometry('300x200')
root.mainloop()
```

I want to use some function in Tkinter, while I am familiar with 'graphics'.
How can I use the function of graphics in this Tkinter window?

Here is the definition of Graphics.

```
# Graphics classes start here

class GraphWin(tk.Canvas):

    """A GraphWin is a toplevel window for displaying graphics."""

    def __init__(self, title="Graphics Window",
                 width=200, height=200, autoflush=True):
        master = tk.Toplevel(_root)
        master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=width, height=height)
        self.master.title(title)
        self.pack()
        master.resizable(0,0)
        self.foreground = "black"
        self.items = []
        self.mouseX = None
        self.mouseY = None
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._onClick)
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self._onKey)
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.autoflush = autoflush
        self._mouseCallback = None
        self.trans = None
        self.closed = False
        master.lift()
        self.lastKey = ""
        if autoflush: _root.update()
```

More is on the http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: I don't know why you would want to… All of the things the Graphics module can do you can do in tkinter.

Comment: Because I'm just a beginner and all I have learnt is Graphics.Would you please tell me how to use them at the same time?

Comment: Graphics window is already Tkinter window - so you could ask how to use Tkinter functions in Graphics window.

Comment: Yes.This is exactly what I want! @furas

Comment: I looked at graphics.py.  While it is written in tkinter, it it not a library meant to used with other tkinter code.  Rather, it is an application library that wraps and hides tkinter.  In this, it is similar to turtle.  However, a turtle screen really is a subclass of Canvas, so is it possible to use turtle within a tkinter program, as with the turtledemo package.  However, while GraphWin subclasses Canvas, it also creates and packs itself within a TopLevel.  So a GraphWin is not a reusable component and cannot be packed within, for instance, a double-paned window as with turtledemo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphics.py library packages the GraphWin object as a toplevel window. If you want to intergrate a GraphWin into a tkinter window with other frames and wigets you need to modify the graphics.py library and remove the toplevel wrapper around the GraphWin class so that it can be treated as a tkinter Canvas. This means you will need to append the modified library in your source file or rename and import it appropriately.

Here is an example of how it could be done in an App that integrates a Graphwin and another tk.Frame in one root window called "root". I will not include the entire modified library here, only the modified GraphWin **init** method, but NOTE -- that alone isn't sufficient -- you will need to go through the rest of the GraphWin class and all of the classes and methods in the library that you want to use; Point, Oval etc.. and change every time you read "_root" to "self.master", and also any time you read "master" should now be "self.master" and any "self.update()" should be "self.master.update()" too.

You may decide that the update() method can be removed, as you can now call self.root.update() with your own self.pauseLength = time.sleep(pauseLength) from inside the yourApp class. All of the occurrences of _root.update() in the graphics classes' methods yourApp might call you will have changed to self.master.update(), so you'll see that inside the modified GraphWin class the self.master is then assigned the parameter root, which must now be provided when you instantiate a GraphWin as in this sample implementation.

```
###################### SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION #######################

import tkinter as tk

class yourApp:
     def __init__(self, yourParameters):
          self.root= tk.Tk()
          self.canvas = GraphWin(self.root, yourParameters)
          self.canvas.pack
          self.frameOfWidgets = tk.Frame(self.root, yourParameters)
          self.frameOfWidgets.pack()

App = yourApp(yourParameters)
App.root.mainloop()

################## MODIFIED GRAPHWIN CLASS #######################


class GraphWin(tk.Canvas):

    """A GraphWin is no longer in a toplevel wrapper and can be treated like a tk.Canvas in the parent window called root."""`

    def __init__(self, root, title="Graphics Window",
                 width=200, height=200, borderwidth=0, autoflush=True):
        self.master = root
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, self.master, width=width, height=height, borderwidth=borderwidth)
        self.master.title(title)
        self.pack()
        self.master.resizable(0, 0)
        self.foreground = "black"
        self.items = []
        self.mouseX = None
        self.mouseY = None
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._onClick)
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self._onKey)
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.autoflush = autoflush
        self._mouseCallback = None
        self.trans = None
        self.closed = False
        self.lastKey = ""
```